# Delete all completed items from list and update local storage

Tags: javascript, crud

I am working on a to-do list project. I want to delete all those items at once which have lines through them by clicking the "clear all completed" button. when I check the box two things happen. First a class by name of "clicked" is added, which does text-decoration: line through. Secondly, It changes the completed boolean from false to true in local storage. you can check the picture below.
I am trying to use the filter method, but, I am unsuccessful. Could anyone please help me, how to delete those items at once, along with removing them from local storage too, which have lines through them.

[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimun reproducible example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would save Completed as a boolean value instead of a string, but with your data as it currently stands, here's one way of doing it:

**Example**

```
const allTasks = localStorage.getItem('todo-list')
const incompleteTasks = allTasks.filter(task => task.Completed === "false")
localStorage.setItem('todo-list', activeTasks)
```